# Oracle running calculation

Tags: oracle

Oracle 19.3
I am looking for a way to calculate avail_qty by date/size based on the data set provided below.

```
create table test
(
avail_date  date
,size_id    varchar2(10)
,purchases  number
,sales      number
,oh_qty     number
);

insert into test values (to_date('3/1/2024','mm/dd/yyyy'),'30',0,0,20);
insert into test values (to_date('3/1/2024','mm/dd/yyyy'),'32',0,0,15);
insert into test values (to_date('3/1/2024','mm/dd/yyyy'),'34',0,5,10);

insert into test values (to_date('3/25/2024','mm/dd/yyyy'),'30',5,0,20);
insert into test values (to_date('3/25/2024','mm/dd/yyyy'),'32',0,1,15);
insert into test values (to_date('3/25/2024','mm/dd/yyyy'),'34',3,5,10);

insert into test values (to_date('4/5/2024','mm/dd/yyyy'),'30',1,0,20);
insert into test values (to_date('4/5/2024','mm/dd/yyyy'),'32',0,0,15);
insert into test values (to_date('4/5/2024','mm/dd/yyyy'),'34',1,1,10);


select * from test
order by avail_date, size_id;
```

I am trying to run following calculation in sql, if possible.

[image]

Comment: your data ca not be inserted because it is short one column https://dbfiddle.uk/tGIvISbU

Comment: corrected table definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that you can use The WINDOW function SUM

But my result is not the same as yours

```
select 
  avail_date  
,size_id    
,purchases  
,sales      
,oh_qty  
  , oh_qty + SUM(purchases  - sales) OVER(PARTITION BY size_id ORDER BY avail_date ASC) avail_qty
  from test
order by avail_date, size_id;
```

| AVAIL_DATE | SIZE_ID | PURCHASES | SALES | OH_QTY | AVAIL_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-MAR-24 | 30 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 20 |
| 01-MAR-24 | 32 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 15 |
| 01-MAR-24 | 34 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 5 |
| 25-MAR-24 | 30 | 5 | 0 | 20 | 25 |
| 25-MAR-24 | 32 | 0 | 1 | 15 | 14 |
| 25-MAR-24 | 34 | 3 | 5 | 10 | 3 |
| 05-APR-24 | 30 | 1 | 0 | 20 | 26 |
| 05-APR-24 | 32 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 14 |
| 05-APR-24 | 34 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yPf4phhs)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I figured out the difference.